# How should I modify this segment of .bst code?

Tags: bibliographies

Could you tell me how to modify this code segment so that the in-text citation always use "et al" for 2 or more authors? This code segment is taken from `apacite.bst`.

```
FUNCTION {tentative.cite.num.names.field}
{ 'field :=
 field num.names$  'numnames :=
 numnames #3 <
   {   %
       % 1 or 2 names: always cite all of them.
       numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
       numnames  'cite.num.names.short :=
   }
   { numnames #6 <
        {  %
           % 3-5 names: cite all of them the first time,
           % only the first name later times
          numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1        'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
        {  %
           % 6 or more names: cite only the first name
          #1  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1  'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
      if$
   }
 if$
}
```

Comment: Did you select this code snippet because you need to work with the `apacite` package and bibliography style?

Comment: No I do not need to stick with the apacite package. However, I need a style similar to APA in every aspect except the in-text citation mentioned in the OP. I am open to any solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like you *do* have to use the `apacite`bib style and package.

Comment: I see. Could you show me how to deal with my issue? I guess a slight modification of the code snippet above should work.

Comment: What about the `apacite` requirement of listing all authors (up to the first six, that is) the very first time a given entry is cited, followed by "FirstAuthor et al"-style for subsequent citation call-outs? Do you want to suppress that as well, i.e., apply truncation even for the first time a given entry is cited?

Comment: Yes. That needs to be suppressed as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried various approaches to modifying (a copy of) `apacite.bst`, but no success. All I can say is that a full solution will require modifying quite a few functions, not just `tentative.cite.num.names.field`. Sorry I can't provide real help.

Comment: That’s ok. Thanks for trying. Do you have any suggestions for an alternative solution to my problem?